# Missing required parameters for [Route:

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a multilingual project, I have a problem with routing and with the "show" function, I'm getting an error:

after entering the address: `projekt.test/en/cars/2/`

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Trying to get property 'marka' of non-object (View: /var/www/projekt/resources/views/cars/show.blade.php)

after entering the address: `projekt.test/pl/categories/3`

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: carsCategories] [URI: {locale}/categories/{id}]. (View: /var/www/projekt/resources/views/template.blade.php) (View: /var/www/projekt/resources/views/template.blade.php)

web.php

```py
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'SetLocale'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('cars/', 'CarController@index')->name('Car');

    Route::get('cars/{id}/', 'CarController@show')->name('cars');

    Route::get('cars/categories/{id}', 'CarController@CarsByCategory')->name('carCategories');
});
```

CarController.php

```py
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Car;

use App\Repositories\CarRepository;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    public function index(CarRepository $carRepository, $locale){

        $cars = $carRepository->getAllCars();
        App::setLocale($locale);
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return view('cars.list',["CarsList"=>$cars,
                                "title"=>"ok"]);
    }

    public function show(CarRepository $carRepository, $id, $locale){

        $carDetail = $carRepository->find($id);
        App::setLocale($locale);
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return view('cars.show', ["carDetail" => $carDetail]);
    }

    public function CarsByCategory(CarRepository $carRepository, $id){

        $cars = $carRepository->getCarsByCategory($id);

        return view('cars.list',["CarsList"=>$cars,
                                "title"=>"ok"]);
    }
}
```

CarRepository.php

```py
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Car;

use DB;

class CarRepository extends BaseRepository {

    public function __construct(Car $model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getAllCars(){

        return $this->model->where('status', 'online')->get();
    }

    public function getCarsByCategory($id){
        return $this->model->where('status', 'online')->whereHas('category',
        function ($query) use ($id) 
        {
            $query->where('categories.id',$id);
        })->orderBy('marka','asc')->get();
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```py
<div class="card-header">
        {{ $carDetail->marka }}
    </div>
```

Comment: you have to debug, try dd( $carDetail ); what this return ?